# Clojure: Custom functions inside Enlive selectors?

Tags: clojure, enlive

Here is an example where I use `html/text` directly inside a selector vector.

```
(:use [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])

(defn fetch-url [url]
  (html/html-resource (java.net.URL. url)))

(defn parse-test []
  (html/select 
   (fetch-url "https://news.ycombinator.com/") 
   [:td.title :a html/text]))
```

Calling `(parse-test)` returns a data structure containing Hacker News Headlines :

```
("In emergency cases a passenger was selected and thrown out of the plane. [2004]" 
 "“Nobody expects privacy online”: Wrong." 
 "The SCUMM Diary: Stories behind one of the greatest game engines ever made" ...)
```

Cool!

Would it be possible to end the selector vector with a custom function that would give me back the list of article URLs.

Something like: `[:td.title :a #(str "https://news.ycombinator.com/" (:href (:attrs %)))]`

**EDIT:**

Here is a way to achieve this. We could write our own select function:

```
(defn select+ [coll selector+]
   (map
     (peek selector+)
     (html/select 
       (fetch-url "https://news.ycombinator.com/") 
       (pop selector+))))

(def href
  (fn [node] (:href (:attrs node))))

(defn parse-test []
  (select+ 
   (fetch-url "https://news.ycombinator.com/") 
   [:td.title :a href]))

(parse-test)
```

Comment: I suspect this is impossible to do. I rather should remove `html/text` from the selector vector and do : `(map #(str "https://news.ycombinator.com/" (:href (:attrs %))) (parse-test))` Or maybe somebody did find a way to get the same result without "escaping the vector" :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggest in your comment, I think it's clearest to keep the selection and the transformation of nodes separate.

Enlive itself provides both selectors *and* transformers. Selectors to find nodes, and transformers to, um, transform them. If your intended output was html, you could probably use a combination of a selector and a transformer to achieve your desired result.

However, seeing as you are just looking for data (a sequence of maps, perhaps?) - you can skip the transform bit, and just use a sequence comprehension, like this:

```
(defn parse-test []
  (for [s (html/select 
            (fetch-url "https://news.ycombinator.com/") 
              [:td.title :a])]
    {:title (first (:content s))
     :link  (:href (:attrs s))}))

(take 2 (parse-test))
;; => ({:title " \tStartup - Bill Watterson, a cartoonist's advice ",
        :link "http://www.zenpencils.com/comic/128-bill-watterson-a-cartoonists-advice"} 
       {:title "Drug Agents Use Vast Phone Trove Eclipsing N.S.A.’s",
        :link "http://www.nytimes.com/2013/09/02/us/drug-agents-use-vast-phone-trove-eclipsing-nsas.html?hp&_r=0&pagewanted=all"})
```